# How to fight spam reviews on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, spam-prevention, review

Somebody posted a spam review to my app (embedded ads and links). Then he had many other spammers flag this review as "helpful". Now this spam review is shown on top of the list as "most helpful". Every day he re-posts this review, so that it stays on top.

I tried flagging this review as spam several times, but it wasn't deleted.
Obviously, there were more "this is helpful" votes than "this is spam" votes.

What can I do to have that spam deleted?

Comment: What do you mean by `spam review` ?

Comment: To be sure we're on the same page; do you mean a review that says something like "Visit dodgySite.com to buy excellent merchandise for low prices"

Comment: spam review: irrelevant ads and links

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 1):

You could [contact google](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=ts.cs&ts=2520903), and they may be able to help.

There is a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331656/protect-from-fake-reviews-on-google-play), from [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11331698/4428462):

> Its also worth checking that there's not a bug in your app that stops it from opening in certain phones/devices (which may or may not be your fault, could be firmware issues). But you'll generally see users select 1 star rather than writing reviews. Remember users are lazy :)